# How to add custom drop down filter in wordpress WP_List_Table

Tags: wordpress

I extended class `WP_List_Table` to display listing records of Custom Database Table. Listing is successful but I'm getting mad about how to implement a drop-down filter to filter my custom db table records according to its categories.

Please share any code to add drop-down filter to filter my custom database table records. Field name is `cat_id`.

Comment: if any expert feels this question incomplete or any questionnaire issue then please inform, i will explain more according to requirements. but please need solution some really quick. Thank you

Comment: Please, Mian, add the soltuion as an ***Answer*** in the box bellow. Take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more, thanks! Oh, the `live` method is deprecated, see jQuery docs.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

after struggle of 3-hours after posting question here, i explored the class, and found the solution, so i am sharing information here.

There is a function function extra_tablenav( $which ), I override that function with my function,

```
function extra_tablenav( $which ) {
    global $wpdb, $testiURL, $tablename, $tablet;
    $move_on_url = '&cat-filter=';
    if ( $which == "top" ){
        ?>
        <div class="alignleft actions bulkactions">
        <?php
        $cats = $wpdb->get_results('select * from '.$tablename.' order by title asc', ARRAY_A);
        if( $cats ){
            ?>
            <select name="cat-filter" class="ewc-filter-cat">
                <option value="">Filter by Category</option>
                <?php
                foreach( $cats as $cat ){
                    $selected = '';
                    if( $_GET['cat-filter'] == $cat['id'] ){
                        $selected = ' selected = "selected"';   
                    }
                    $has_testis = false;
                    $chk_testis = $wpdb->get_row("select id from ".$tablet." where banner_id=".$cat['id'], ARRAY_A);
                    if( $chk_testis['id'] > 0 ){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $move_on_url . $cat['id']; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $cat['title']; ?></option>
                <?php   
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <?php   
        }
        ?>  
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    if ( $which == "bottom" ){
        //The code that goes after the table is there

    }
}
```

and then I jumped into function prepare_items() and added a line after query string,

```
if( $_GET['cat-filter'] > 0 ){
            $query = $query . ' where cat_id=' . $_GET['cat-filter'];   
        }
```

not finished here, I added some lines of javascript to execute drop down,

```
$('.ewc-filter-cat').live('change', function(){
    var catFilter = $(this).val();
    if( catFilter != '' ){
        document.location.href = 'admin.php?page=ewc-testimonial'+catFilter;    
    }
});
```

and its working cool and fine, if anybody need more help then comment here.

Thank you for time.

Comment: sorry for using live method of jQuery, you should use recommended approach as mentioned in above comment by brasofilo.

Comment: how do you do it with the filter button?

Comment: Make sure you wrap anything that's going straight from `$_GET` into a query in the `mysql_real_escape_string` function, otherwise you leave yourself open to sql injection.

Comment: e.g. `$query = $query . ' where cat_id=' . $_GET['cat-filter'];` should be `$query = $query . ' where cat_id=' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat-filter']);`

Comment: how to call  extra_tablenav() ?

Comment: As it will be a function of the extended class so call it as $object->extra_tablenav()

Comment: Thank you very much! Very useful ... the documentation of WP_List_Table is really bad

Comment: 2014 wasn't too early to use mysqli_* thing.

Comment: I had to use `display_tablenav()` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Ben that worked great. I just grabbed the source function from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/display_tablenav/ and customized it to my needs.